# Editing an SVG file using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, vector

There is a photo that has already been added to the HTML code(as svg file). I would like to know: how to make it so that the user can choose between two options - a cross or a zero and by clicking on the area, a cross or a zero appears. (i.e. when choosing one of the two and clicking LMB on the area, the selected figure appears (if you can call it that).

I will be glad for help.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like that? You cn simply place the svgs insite the option divs

```html
`<div class="">
<div id="option-1" style="display: none;">Cross</div>
<div id="option-2" style="display: none;">Zero</div>
<button class="" onclick="document.getElementById('option-1').style.display = 'block'; document.getElementById('option-2').style.display = 'none'; ">Cross</button>
<button class="" onclick="document.getElementById('option-2').style.display = 'block'; document.getElementById('option-1').style.display = 'none'; ">Zero</button>
</div>`
```

Comment: Thank you, but I  wanted another thing: I want to let person choose what he wants to place on the photo: cross or zero. To be clear, there's a photo of the person's face and the doctor need to place zero or cross on it by clicking LMB and write under it something. The original photo should be as svg.